# How can I read a python django project URL and display complete webpage in email with it's CSS and javascript working

Tags: python, django, urllib

I have a django project setup, I'm trying to fetch one URL using python urllib module by making a request. It is fetching the complete HTML of that page, and I'm passing that HTML with smtp module to send email.

Now that web page is displayed in email body, but all the CSS and javascript didn't work as expected, so only some parts of the webpage were displayed in email body (only the basic HTML ones). What can I do to make the complete web page get displayed in the email itself just like it's displayed on a web browser.

Comment: Short answer: you can't. Web pages are meant to be viewed in browsers and you can't just copy them into an email. It just won't work. No email client will parse scripts, and very few if any will parse external CSS. Not to mention that many websites use relative paths for assets like images and these would completely break outside the context of the website.

Answer (score 2):

Because of the limitations and variability of how email clients render HTML it won't be possible to display HTML from web pages directly in emails. If the web pages you're talking about have been designed to work with email clients then you could use a library like [premailer](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/premailer) to absolutize links and inline stylesheets.

If the web pages haven't been designed for email clients, you could use a library such as [pdfkit](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pdfkit) to convert HTML to PDF:

```
import pdfkit
pdfkit.from_url('http://google.com', 'out.pdf')
```

Then attach the generated PDF file to the email. Of course, this won't allow someone to interact with the web pages.